# Generating all possible combinations

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

I'm writing some code and ended up with this problem. I have N products and I have to form all possible combinations of these products, form a product catalog and find some properties, like price. In order to do this I have to form the catalog of products from the given products (exhaustively, but no duplicates allowed). Is there a standardized algorithm for doing this? Note that the catalogs can contain any positive number of products.

Comment: permutation = order matters (an ordered list). combination = order doesn't matter (a set).

Comment: ok . Then I guess this is combination

Comment: If it's a combination you can just do: `for i = 1 to 2^N` and use bit hax... I think...

Comment: Voting to close. Problem's underspecified so we can't tell what you are trying to do (generate all permutations? all combinations? of size K?). You will have to be a lot more specific. Also finding all the permutations of a catalog of size 100 would take so long, that the universe would end before you finished. You probably don't want that if your catalog   is larger than 10 items. I assume your catalog probably has something like hundreds of items. If what you want are K-combinations, those scale like N^K. e.g. printing out all 10-sets would take longer than the age of the universe.

Comment: `any positive number` is much too vague. For very small numbers, the problem is solvable in memory, but soon it isn't. `exhaustively` is a word, you surely don't like to hear in that context. See yi_H's answer, and think about 2^65 combinations for 65 elements.

Comment: Well now i'm feeling foolish askin this question, i really had no idea the combination(not permutuation) was goin to be so HUGE . And considering the fact that i need all combinations (not just of size k) makes it even more difficult . may be there's a easy way around , i must see to it

Comment: @quasiverse Where did you learn the bit-hack combination method? I [independently invented it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3689817/57611) but I wonder how long it's been around.

Comment: @ErikE Well... I learnt it from various algorithm competitions and related preparations. E.g. [topcoder.com's algorithm tutorials](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=bitManipulation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first few sections of The Art of Computer Programming, vol. 3, Sorting and Searching discusses Inversion and Permutation (of a set and multisets) in great detail. In this case it is important to dabble in theory a bit, see what's out there. The code will follow, but if this is "leisure time coding", why not do it including "leisure time theory" as well? Betcha it's going to be cool, you'll know the whats but you'll also know the whys!

Answer (score 5):

Combinations can be represented by a bit-vector. If a bit is set, the element is present in the combination.

So you simply have to enumarte all numbers from 1 to 2^N-1 (from 0000001, last element present till 1111111, all elements present), and will represent a possible combination.

Comment: I'm using integers (as an index into array as of now) as the products . Is there a way to proceed from this set up rather than writing up new code :-(

Comment: well, if you don't want to decode the numbers you could implement your own binary incrementer (each index in the array is a binary digit). You could also use some clever gray code generator to enumerate all numbers http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code

Comment: Ya i've already written a lot and reimplementing will be timeconsumin

Comment: @Malice: You should show us the code, if you want us reuse it.

Comment: @Karoly where did you learn this method? I [independently invented it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3689817/57611) but I wonder how long it's been around.

Answer (score 2):

A naive implementation to print all combination of characters from a give string:

```
void print_combination(char* str, char* buffer, int len, int num, int pos)                                                                 
{
  if(num == 0)
  {
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  for(int i = pos; i < len - num + 1; ++i)
  {
    buffer[num - 1] = str[i];
    print_combination(str, buffer, len, num - 1, i + 1);
  }
}

int main()
{
  char str[] = "abcde";
  char buffer[6];
  for(auto i = 1u; i <= sizeof(str); ++i)
  {
    buffer[i] = '\0';
    print_combination(str, buffer, 5, i, 0);
  }
}
```

Quite simple but may have performance problem. Take it if it could help.

If you're looking for permutation(I can't tell from your description), I implemented the algorithm in The Art of Computer Programming:

```
template <typename Iter>                                                                                                                   
bool next_permutation(Iter start, Iter end)
{
  if(start == end)
    return false;

  Iter i = start + 1;
  if(i == end)
    return false;

  i = end - 1;

  while(true)
  {
    Iter ii = i;
    --i;
    if(*i < *ii)
    {
      Iter j = end;
      while(*i >= *--j);
      std::iter_swap(i, j);
      std::reverse(ii, end);
      return true;
    }
    if(i == start)
    {
      std::reverse(start, end);
      return false;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  char str1[] = "abcde";
  do
  {
    std::cout << str1 << std::endl;
  } while(next_permutation(&str1[0], &str1[5]));
}
```

It's quite efficient and C++ stl algorithm uses the same algorithm.

Comment: The first algorithm prints only combinations with 5 characters right ?

Comment: @Malice I used a loop in the main function to print the combinations of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in python, using [itertools.combinations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) in following way:

```
import itertools

products = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4']
for L in range(1, len(products)+1):
      for subset in itertools.combinations(products, L):
              print(subset)
```

what gives as result:

```
('p1',)
('p2',)
('p3',)
('p4',)
('p1', 'p2')
('p1', 'p3')
('p1', 'p4')
('p2', 'p3')
('p2', 'p4')
('p3', 'p4')
('p1', 'p2', 'p3')
('p1', 'p2', 'p4')
('p1', 'p3', 'p4')
('p2', 'p3', 'p4')
('p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4')
```

Solution inspired by [this answer of @dan-h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/python-code-to-pick-out-all-possible-combinations-from-a-list/5898031#5898031).