# More efficient way to find all combinations?

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, collections, combinations

Say you have a `List` of `Strings` or whatever, and you want to produce another `List` which will contain every possible combination of two `strings` from the original `list` (concated together), is there any more efficient way to do this other than using a nested `for` loop to combine the String with all the others?

Some sample code:

```
 for(String s: bytes) {
            for(String a: bytes) {
                if(!(bytes.indexOf(a) == bytes.indexOf(s))) {
                    if(s.concat(a).length() == targetLength) {
                        String combination = s.concat(a);
                        validSolutions.add(combination);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The time for execution gets pretty bad pretty quickly as the size of the original `list` of `Strings` grows.

Any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229743/generating-all-possible-combinations

Comment: The `IndexOfs` are the problem. can you just compare a and s directly?

Comment: @Jimmy, I don't think I can because there are duplicate strings which make up a valid combination, e.g "abc" and "abc" makes "abcabc" so if I do a.equals(s) that's not gonna really work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid checking `i != j` condition by setting `j = i + 1`. Also, things like `bytes.length()` get evaluated at each iteration of both loops - save it into a value and reuse. Calling `a.length()` inside the loop asks for a length of the same string multiple times - you can save some runtime on that as well. Here are the updates:

```
int len = bytes.length();
int aLength;
String a, b;
for(int i=0; i<len; i++) {
  a = bytes[i];
  aLength = a.length();
  for(int j=i; j<len; j++) {
    b = bytes[j];
    if (b.length() + aLength == targetLength) {
      validSolutions.add(b.concat(a));
      validSolutions.add(a.concat(b));
    }
  }
}
```

Edit: `j = i` because you want to consider a combination of a string with itself; Also, you'd need to add `a.concat(b)` as well since this combination is never considered in the loop, but is a valid string

Comment: awesome. i was keeping count of the number of operations and using j=i+1 cut the number of operations in half. beautiful!

Comment: If you're only considering each pair of strings once, instead of twice in both orders, shouldn't you add both `b.concat(a)` and `a.concat(b)` to `validSolutions`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't get Better than **O(N^2)**, because there are that many combinations. But you could speed up your algorithm a bit (from **O(N^3)**) by removing the `indexOf` calls:

```
for(int i=0; i<bytes.length(); i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<bytes.length(); j++) {
        string s = bytes[i];
        string a = bytes[j];
        if (i != j && s.length() + a.length() == targetLength) {
            validSolutions.add(s.concat(a));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Jimmy and lynxoid say, the fact that the total length is constrained gives you a further optimization. Sort your strings in order of length, then for each `s` you know that you require only the `a`s such that `a.length() == targetLength - s.length()`.

So as soon as you hit a string longer than that you can break out of the inner loop (since all the rest will be longer), and you can start at the "right" place for example with a lower-bound binary search into the array.

Complexity is still O(n^2), since in the worst case all the strings are the same length, equal to half of `totalLength`. Typically though it should go somewhat better than considering all pairs of strings.