# T-SQL :: use GROUP BY CUBE to generate all possible combinations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cube, olap-cube

In a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686062/generate-all-combinations-in-sql) I found that I can use `GROUP BY CUBE` to find all possible combinations:

```
select concat(a,b,c,d)
from (select 'a','b','c','d') as t(a,b,c,d)
group by cube(a,b,c,d)
having len(concat(a,b,c,d)) = 3
```

The code is pretty because is very easy to understand.
I would like to use the same code but with `int` instead of `char`. Basically I would like to find all possible combinations of numbers (1,2,3,4).

The goal is to sum them and generate all possible totals:

- 1 + 2 + 3 = 6
- 2 + 3 + 4 = 7
- 3 + 4 + 1 = 8
- etc..

I'm trying to resolve a [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) in T-SQL and I would like to see if `GROUP BY CUBE` can be a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take `NULL`s into account more explicitly, but something like this:

```
select coalesce(a, 0) + coalesce(b, 0) + coalesce(c, 0) + coalesce(d, 0)
from (values (1, 2, 3, 4)) t(a,b,c,d)
group by cube(a,b,c,d)
having (case when a is not null then 1 else 0 end +
        case when b is not null then 1 else 0 end +
        case when c is not null then 1 else 0 end +
        case when d is not null then 1 else 0 end
       ) = 3;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=98b0b47e401e11489cda8ea8ae03f9fe) is a db<>fiddle.

I should note that an alternative method of doing this uses explicit joins:

```
with t as (
      select t.*
      from (values (1), (2), (3), (4)) t(x)
     )
select t1.x + t2.x + t3.x
from t t1 join
     t t2
     on t1.x < t2.x join
     t t3
     on t2.x < t3.x;
```

These are not exactly the same if the values can be repeated.  However, you might find that the `join` version is faster on larger amounts of data.

Comment: Is there a way to put a limit like "select only values lower than 8"?

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani . . . You would add a `having` clause:  `coalesce(a, 0) + coalesce(b, 0) + coalesce(c, 0) + coalesce(d, 0) < 8`.